# JQuery Smooth Div Scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, html

So here is my issue.

I am using smoothdDivScrolling on my page.

For some reason the Scrollable area that contain all the items i want to scroll is always bigger then the actual content.

So when i reach the last item in the scrollable area it keep scrolling empty.  It seams that smoothdivscrolling auto adjust the width of the scrollable area to twice the value i need!

Now you probably want some code to see what i mean so...

```
<figure  id='block$id'>
 <img src='$img' alt='image $name' />
 <h2>$name</h2>
</figure>
```

This is the items i have in my

```
<div class="scrollableArea"></div>
```

And of course i have more then one. and they are scrolling as expected

Now the CSS code for my figure element is as follow

```
figure {

    display:block;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:172px;
    height:125px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border:12px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-radius:8px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 13px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 13px #999;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 13px #999;
    margin:5px;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index:199;
}
```

They are displaying corectly. Now i was wondering why does my scrollable area is twice the size of my content.

CSS of my scrolable area :

```
div.scrollableArea
{   
   display: block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:190px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

As you can see i dont provide a width value but even if i do and no mather if its a fixed value or the auto value. The result is always the same.

Here is the line that call for smoothdivscrolling

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
autoScroll: "onstart", 
autoScrollDirection: "backandforth", 
autoScrollStep: 2,
autoScrollInterval: 15, 
startAtElementId: "startme", 
visibleHotSpots: "always"
});
```

If you would like to see more of my code please let me know i really want to get this fixed.

Thank you

Comment: Anyway you can link to the page? Or a gist/pen?

Comment: it looks like it's doubling the width exactly.

Comment: I know right! i tought it was becuse of my images inside figures that have the same width but if i change it it remain the same.  Could it be becuse im calling smoothdiv scrolling twice? Cuse i use it for the image behind MID in the header.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Try adding a second jquery function which reduces the width by half, after the document has loaded, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var initialW = $('selector').width();
    $('selector').css('width', initialW/2);
});
```

Comment: While this answer is valid, it may be better with an explanation. See [Help Center > How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*.

Comment: I really tought that was it but nope. its not working. i have replace selector by the ID of the DIV and also try replacing it by the name off the css class none of them work. No mather what width i give to scrollableArea it never changes.i think it has to do with the way i center my page (800px) into another DIV by using margin auto; So anyone looking at my page will see it 800px wie in the center of what ever they have for resolution